# Does a USB hub fall under the definition of 'backplane'?

Tags: usb

I am just curious if a typical USB hub with a couple ports for devices falls under the definition of a backplane.

Comment: This is symantic word-splitting.  Why does it matter?

Comment: Which definition of a backplane? Functionally it probably does, but the implementation is generally just 1 chip. You might still argue that that chip has a backbone inside it, but as you can't connect anything to it that is not your average backplane.

Answer (score 1):

No. A back plane typically offers parallel connections on a computer bus. As USB is a serial point to point bus, with no interoperability between devices,  it can't be considered a back plane. An ide/pata 2 device cable could be considered one.

Comment: There's nothing about any common definition of "backplane" that implies that direct device-to-device communication is required. There are many instances of single-master backplanes in all kinds of applications.

Answer (score 1):

USB as a whole is a *logical* backplane, but it is *physically* implemented as a network of point-to-point connections. A hub is just one node in that network that does the aggregation (multiplexing and distributing) of the traffic between the upstream (host) port and the downstream (device) ports.